# Java random class, need to randomize only 0,10, 20,30,40,50 instead of any number in that range

Tags: java, random

Need help with my java program, I know how to use the random class to generate a random number up to a certain number; but for this specific program I need to generate a random number out of 0 ,10 ,20 ,30 ,40 , and 50.

Comment: probably a homework assignment, so think about how you could get a random range and then do some math to the result of it, which will get you what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Generate a number in the range of [0, 5], then multiply it by 10.

Answer (score 1):

First generate a randomNumber in the range 0-5 and then multiply it times 10

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNum = 10 * random.nextInt(6);
```